# Trouble getting AL8861 LED Driver to illuminate LEDs

Tags: led-driver

I am trying to get a [AL8861](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL8861.pdf) LED driver hooked up. Right now I've connected it to a single LED ([this one](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/cree-inc/XPGDRY-L1-0000-00601/XPGDRY-L1-0000-00601CT-ND/7134718)) to test (see circuit below). I eventually intend to connect it to a [DAC5578](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/DAC5578SPWR/296-41234-1-ND/5222694) Digital to Analog converter to communicate via I2C. For now, I'd like to test if the lighting circuit works.

UPDATE:
I found the primary issue - my board had an error with GND not being connected to the driver for that channel. Now I have light, but not very bright. Connecting VSET to GND or 3v3 doesn't seem to do anything. CH1+ reads 2.54v and CH1- is 0v. Still stumped...

[image: AL8861 Wiring Diagram]

[image: LED]

I've connected the components and supplied 24v. As soon as I plugged it in, the LED flashed and then went dark. I've also tried connecting VSET to ground, and it begins to glow slowly but remains very dim. I tried connecting VSET to +3v and +5v (probably a bad idea) and it flashed again. Now when I connect VSET to ground I get no glow.

I get some weird results when I check the test pads voltages. Here are the readings:

- (+24v) 24.30v
- (VSET) 23.93v
- (CH1+) 24.30v
- (CH1-) 24.27v

I thought VSET would float. When I connect it to ground, it has ~60mA of current running through it.

Is my circuit wrong in some way? I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Edit: 
Here's a picture of the circuit board, if that helps. I haven't yet added the indicator LED / resistor:
[image: PCB]

Comment: Can you explain why you added C72?

Comment: This is a small section of [this PCB](https://github.com/OpenAgInitiative/openag-electrical/tree/master/prj/pfc-edu/v4.0) I'm using / modding from MIT OpenAg. I wasn't the original designer, so I don't know why that component is there. I do see that capacitor in [the wiring diagram on page 3](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Evaluation-Boards/AL8861EV1-User-Guide.pdf) from an AL8861 user guide (C4), so I assume it's ok?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out – it was two things:

Something in the board must have been soldered improperly, because I reflowed everything and tested all connections, plugged it back in and it was suddenly working as expected.

The LED isn't shining as bright as I would have expected because of the RS2 resistor value. The formula in the datasheet is Current = .1/R. Right now my RS2 is 6.34ohms, which is 15mA. To run this much higher, I will need a resistor value between .1 and .15 ohms (I didn't even know these existed).

Hope this helps anyone else out there with this chip!